# (Flutter) _RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, firebase-authentication

I am creating the login and registration page for a flutter app. In the `main.dart` I am calling `HomePage()` as home property. Then in the `Home_Page.dart`, I am initializing the firebase in the Home_page(). Then using a switch statement if the connection state is done it goes to Login_page(), then if we click on the register button at the bottom of `login_page.dart` it goes to `Registration_page.dart`. This is the flow of control. Now in between these steps, the while debugging an error occurs in debug console which is

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: _RenderSingleChildViewport#233b4 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(411.4, Infinity)

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints.<anonymous closure>
#1      RenderBox.debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints
#2      RenderBox.size=.<anonymous closure>
#3      RenderBox.size=
#4      RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
#5      RenderObject.layout
#6      RenderBox.layout
#7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#8      RenderObject.layout
#9      RenderBox.layout
#10     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#11     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
#12     RenderObject.layout
#13     RenderBox.layout
#14     _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout
#15     RenderObject.layout
#16     RenderBox.layout
#17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#18     RenderObject.layout
#19     RenderBox.layout
#20     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#21     RenderObject.layout
#22     RenderBox.layout
#23     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#24     RenderObject.layout
#25     RenderBox.layout
#26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#27     RenderObject.layout
#28     RenderBox.layout
#29     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#30     RenderObject.layout
#31     RenderBox.layout
#32     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#33     RenderObject.layout
#34     RenderBox.layout
#35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#36     RenderObject.layout
#37     RenderBox.layout
#38     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#39     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
#40     RenderObject.layout
#41     RenderBox.layout
#42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#43     RenderObject.layout
#44     RenderBox.layout
#45     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
#46     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
#47     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
#48     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
#49     RenderObject.layout
#50     RenderBox.layout
#51     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#52     RenderObject.layout
#53     RenderBox.layout
#54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#55     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
#56     RenderObject.layout
#57     RenderBox.layout
#58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
#59     RenderObject.layout
#60     RenderBox.layout
#61     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
#62     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
#63     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
#64     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
#65     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
#66     PipelineOwner.flushLayout
#67     RendererBinding.drawFrame
#68     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
#69     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
#70     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
#71     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
#72     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
#73     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13)
#74     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5)
#75     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#6ca1e relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#6ca1e relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    size: Size(411.4, Infinity)
    child 1: RenderConstrainedBox#ca2a2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=820.6)
        child: RenderDecoratedBox#5b13e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: <none>
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            decoration: BoxDecoration
                gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topRight, end: Alignment.bottomLeft, colors: [Color(0xff000000), MaterialAccentColor(primary value: Color(0xff69f0ae)), Color(0xff000000)], tileMode: TileMode.clamp)
            configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#f1631(), devicePixelRatio: 3.5, locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
            child: RenderRepaintBoundary#6790e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                needs compositing
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                usefulness ratio: no metrics collected yet (never painted)
                child: RenderCustomPaint#b8e1a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                    parentData: <none>
                    constraints: MISSING
                    size: MISSING
                    painter: null
                    foregroundPainter: _GlowingOverscrollIndicatorPainter(_GlowController(color: Color(0xff2196f3), axis: vertical), _GlowController(color: Color(0xff2196f3), axis: vertical))
    child 2: RenderStack#57ee1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight
        textDirection: ltr
        fit: loose
        child 1: RenderTransform#0d1ac NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            transform matrix: [0] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[1] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
            origin: null
            alignment: Alignment.center
            textDirection: ltr
            transformHitTests: true
            child: RenderTransform#06de2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                transform matrix: [0] 0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[1] -0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
                origin: null
                alignment: Alignment.center
                textDirection: ltr
                transformHitTests: true
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
_RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Restarted application in 844ms.

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

the code of the code for `main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_mythology/Pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:my_mythology/Pages/login_page.dart';
import 'package:my_mythology/Pages/registeration_page.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[350],
      ),
      routes: {
        '/login/' :(context)=> LoginPage(),
        '/register/':(context) => RegisterationPage(),
      },
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the code for `home_page.dart`

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_mythology/Pages/login_page.dart';

import '../firebase_options.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [
              Colors.black,
              Colors.greenAccent,
              Colors.black,
            ])),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: Firebase.initializeApp(
                options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  return const LoginPage();
                default:
                  return Text("Loading....");
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the code for `login_page.dart`

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart";
import "package:my_mythology/firebase_options.dart";

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  late final TextEditingController _email;
  late final TextEditingController _password;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: Container(
        
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [
              Colors.black,
              Colors.greenAccent,
              Colors.black,
            ])),
        
          child :
          
          
           SingleChildScrollView(
            
            
              
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: Firebase.initializeApp(
                    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.done:
                      return Column(
                        
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 150,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: const [
                              Text(
                                "Login",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 50,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 80),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50, left: 50),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                TextFormField(
                                  controller: _email,
                                  enableSuggestions: true,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'E-Mail',
                                      hintText: "Yourname@example.com ",
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )),
                                ),
                                TextFormField(
                                  controller: _password,
                                  obscureText: true,
                                  enableSuggestions: false,
                                  autocorrect: false,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Password',
                                      hintText: "yourpassword",
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 50),
                          Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: 150,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.black45,
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    final email = _email.text;
                                    final password = _password.text;
                                    try {
                                      Firebase.initializeApp(
                                          options: DefaultFirebaseOptions
                                              .currentPlatform);
                                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                                      if (e.code == "User not found") ;
                                      {
                                        print("User not found");
                                      }
                                    }
                                    await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                            email: email, password: password);
                                  },
                                  child: const Text("Login",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25)),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 100,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                const Text("Don't Have A account? Create One",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
                                Row(
                                  children:  [
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/register/'),
                                      child: Text("Register",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
                                    ),
                                    Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                                        color: Colors.white)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    default:
                      return Text("Loading....");
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          
        ),
      );
    
  }
}
```

the code for `registration_page.dart`

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart";
import "package:my_mythology/firebase_options.dart";

class RegisterationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterationPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterationPage> createState() => _RegisterationPageState();
}

class _RegisterationPageState extends State<RegisterationPage> {
  late final TextEditingController _email;
  late final TextEditingController _password;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [
              Colors.black,
              Colors.greenAccent,
              Colors.black,
            ])),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 150,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Register",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 50,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 80),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50, left: 50),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: _email,
                              enableSuggestions: true,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'E-Mail',
                                  hintText: "Yourname@example.com ",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: _password,
                              obscureText: true,
                              enableSuggestions: false,
                              autocorrect: false,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Password',
                                  hintText: "yourpassword",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 50),
                      Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: Colors.black45,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                final email = _email.text;
                                final password = _password.text;
                                await Firebase.initializeApp(
                                    options:
                                        DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
                                try {
                                  await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                          email: email, password: password);
                                } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                                  if (e.code == "weak-password") {
                                    print("Weak Message");
                                  } else if (e.code == "email-already-in-use") {
                                    print("Email Already In use");
                                  } else if (e.code == "invalid-email ") {
                                    print("Invalid Email");
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              child: const Text("Register",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25)),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            const Text("Already Have a Account? ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
                            Row(
                              children: const [
                                Text("Login",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15)),
                                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                                    color: Colors.white)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                default:
                  return Center(child: Text("Loading...."));
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Github Link->https://github.com/ramanjitsingh-hub/My_Mythology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove this error first remove `singlechildscrollview` as the parent of the `futurebuilder` . Now in the build function of the future builder add `singlechildscrollview` as the parent of column we are returning.

```
  return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [
              Colors.black,
              Colors.greenAccent,
              Colors.black,
            ])),
        child: FutureBuilder(
           future: Firebase.initializeApp(
                    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.done:
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 150,
                      ),
```

add the height and width to the container to remove white spaces at the bottom.

Do this for both of the pages `Login_page.dart` and `Registeration_page.dart`

This will fix the error .

the small error in the code is that the future property of `futurebuilder` is missing in the `futurebuilder` of `Registeration_Page.dart`. This is the reason that the registration page always returns `Loading`

Answer (score 0):

Please add height and width for the container in home page. You have added a container and assigned a SingleChildScrollView as its child which has no bounds

Comment: so I need to add the height and width container

Comment: Yeah please add height for the constraints that's wrapping SingleChildScrollView

Comment: the error is not resolved

Comment: In which class do you get the error?

Comment: in front of the error it says Login_page.dart line 33

Comment: In the column of login_page add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`

Comment: Should I add it the first column which is returned if the connection state is true